# Docker seccomp error after upgrade from debian 8 to debian 9

Tags: docker, seccomp

The following error occurs during `docker run` and `docker build` after upgrading from Debian 8 to Debian 9:

```
ERROR: Service 'etherpad' failed to build: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "error loading seccomp filter into kernel: invalid argument": unknown
```

I was able to solve the problem when running a container by using `--seccomp-profile:unconfined` but build doesn't support this flag (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21105). I also tried to pass it to the daemon via the daemon.json but this caused an error during startup.

Kernel support is enabled:

```
grep CONFIG_SECCOMP= /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_SECCOMP=y
```

docker info:

```
Containers: 38
Running: 9
Paused: 0
Stopped: 29
Images: 119
Server Version: 18.09.2
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 275
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries     splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9754871865f7fe2f4e74d43e2fc7ccd237edcbce
runc version: 09c8266bf2fcf9519a651b04ae54c967b9ab86ec
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
 WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
 Profile: /root/labs/security/seccomp/seccomp-profiles/default.json
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-7-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.71GiB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Docker containers can't (or at least really really shouldn't) make changes to the host kernel.  You especially can't do this during the `docker build` step.  Also note the output of the build is essentially a filesystem image with metadata, and not any of the other running state of the system: if you succeeded at this, pushed the image, and ran it from somewhere else, it wouldn't have whatever kernel-related change you were making.

Comment: Aside - recommend moving off the aufs storage driver.

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR;** reboot your server after upgrading to Stretch.

---

Your issue looks similar to one that I experienced. I received the below error:

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "error loading seccomp filter into kernel: invalid argument": unknown
```

The issue occurred after upgrading from Jessie to Stretch and installing a fresh copy of Docker (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/).

I believe your issue is similar because your docker info output shows

```
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-7-amd64
```

and for me:

```
# uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.59-1 (2018-10-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Stretch should be using a later kernel version than that, so the fix was:

```
# reboot
# uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u2 (2019-05-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After updating kernel docker starts.
1. `apt-cache search linux-image` have follow: `linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64 - Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs` and `linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64` 2. `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64` 3. `docker run hello-world`